# creating dynamic views at runtime asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I'm fairly new to mvc, and have started learning asp.net mvc 5 and django

I want to create an application where the user can create a new view at runtime. So lets say I create a feature in the web app for a user to add a new page where they can fill out a form, say the title maybe text, or fields they want to display on the view, and when the user saves it that info gets saved to the db and creates a new view.

My questions are:

- can you create dynamic views at runtime?
- how do you create the proper url to route to that new page?
- if the 1st two are possible can you use a model or viewModel to then display the content from the db for that page?

Any advice on if this can be done would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to make a page that saves the user configuration in db as per user demand.

From my end, I suggest the following approach to do it.

1. Whatever you gets the data from database which are returns like as below snap.

[image]

2. Make one Action in controller and assign those data in one datatable/list in action.

   public ActionResult LoadContent()
       {

   ```
   dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
   var model = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;


   /*Let say user insert the detail of employee registration form. Make the     
   database call and get the distinct detail of particular inserted form by Id   
   or whatever. As an example below datatable contains the data that you fetch  
   during database call.*/


   DataTable objListResult =    
   HeaderViewActionHelper.GetFinalResultToRenderInGenericList(id);


   if (objListResult != null && objListResult.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
     foreach (DataRow row in objListResult.Rows)
     {
       model.Add(row["DisplayName"].ToString(),    
       row["DisplayNameValue"].ToString());

   /*If you want to handle the datatype of each field than you can bifurcation   
   the type here using If..else or switch..case. For that you need to return   
   another column in your result from database i.e. DataType coloumn. Add in   
   your model as, model.Add(row["DisplayName"].ToString(),   
   row["DisplayNameValue"].ToString(), row["DataType"].ToString());*/

     }
   }


   /* return the model in view. */
       return View(model);
   }
   ```
3. In the view you can go through the loop over modal and render the detail.

   ```
   @model dynamic

   @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitActionName", "ControllerName")
    {
    <div class="table-responsive">
     <table>
         @if (Model != null)
             {
                foreach (var row in Model)
                 {

                 }
             }
     </table>

   </div>
   }
   ```

For more detail, Please go through [this](http://blogs.quovantis.com/dynamic-models-for-mvc-view/) link.

Comment: I dont think will work because this is not dynamic views